# VS Code Python Environment

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Python in VS Code. I cannot select Python Environment unless i ran VS Code as administrator. Is there a setting within VS Code that allows to set environment for regular user?

Comment: What errors you get ? did you try : python -m venv env and then env/Scripts/activate.bat ?

Comment: @J.K I get command 'python.setInterpreter' not found.

Comment: Please try to debug your file, using F5 in VS code, and this should activate your environment automatically. Let me know if you receive the same error.

Comment: @J.K Not sure if I am doing it correct. I started debug console. Then went to Command Pallete and got the same error message. Nothing was logged on debug console.

Comment: Have you looked into this: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).  It shows how to set/select an interpreter.  Also check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/781) out

Comment: @SanV. I did. It works as expected only if I ran VS Code as administrator. I want to know the settings to be able to do it as regular user

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way around this is to use the iPython extension. This extension for VS code is really great for using python commands in vs code without any environment problems.